# CompareTo Method

Tags: java, compareto

I finally think I found a way to sort my transactions by amount using the if statement but I need a way to indicate when one transaction is less or greater than the other they exchange places.

I have a sample of what I've done so far and not too sure what I am missing out here.

```
    @Override
public int compareTo(Student_Transaction Tra)
{    
    if (getAmount() == ((Student_Transaction) Tra).getAmount()) {
        return Amount - Tra.getAmount();
    }
    else if (getAmount() > ((Student_Transaction) Tra).getAmount()) { 
        return 1;
    }
    else if (getAmount() < ((Student_Transaction) Tra).getAmount()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return Amount;
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting `Tra` to `Student_Transaction`. It is already passed in as a `Student_Transaction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you go with:

```
return Double.compare(this.amount, tra.getAmount());
```

which means, you can avoid having to do all those `if`/`else if` conditions.

Comment: Of course if either `this.amount` or `tra.getAmount()` return a null Double, the unboxing to double will throw a NPE.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas where does it say `amount` is nullable? do you think the OPs approach wouldn't throw an exception in such a case? let's leave those assumptions to the OP.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I will go for the Float.Compare because my variable amount is float data type.

Comment: return Double.compare(this.amount, tra.getAmount()); Therefore AOMINE to conclude, this line of code will compare the current object vs the stored object an then re arrange in correct order! Hence I can still use queue to store my transactions but using Compare interface to sort.

Comment: @Aomine Since the OP neglected to post the actual declared data type in the question, I thought it was reasonable to point out that if the variable were of type `Double` (or equivalent numerical wrapper), which could potentially be null, this would lead to a possible NPE. Future readers may also be unaware of this possibility.

Comment: Interesting adn Could introduce possible risks but if that does happen I know where to look when diagnosing the problem :) thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

This is `compareTo` method of `Student_Stransaction`, so no need to use getters:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student_Transaction Tra) {
    return Tra != null ? Float.compare(amount, Tra.amount)) : 1;
}
```

Comment: So a `null` object will be greater than a **non** `null` object?

Answer (score 0):

I literally realised that what I did in the thread above was the answer to my question, it clearly defined how I will sort my amounts in each transaction object the final fold of this stage was to use the collection.sort method and in one of the recent threads I have posted the answer to how it is done...

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student_Transaction Tra){
    if (Tra.getAmount() < getAmount()) { 
        return -1; 
    }
    else if (Tra.getAmount() == getAmount()) { 
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1; // Tra.getAmount() > getAmount()
    }
}
```

I didn't need to go the extra mile, ya boy just is misunderstood with his programming and I'm much appreciated with have this community of professional programmers dedicating their time to help people like me out :)